# set workspace for MavensMate projects on Mac OS

Tags: mavensmate

I followed [link](http://www.oyecode.com/2014/01/mavensmate-forcecom-ide-for-salesforce.html) .But I am getting below error on step 5 for OSX (workspace path like /Users/Andy Ray/Documents/mm_workspace)

**Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages/User/mavensmate.sublime-settings:1:1**

Comment: You need a backspace preceding any spaces in your path name, I wonder if this is the issue: /Users/Andy\ Ray/Documents/mm_workspace

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same problem as well. Doing it like this fixed it for me:

```
{ "mm_workspace" : "/Users/<name>/Documents/mavensmate" }
```

EDIT: Expanded explanation for clarification: The configuration files for MM are in JSON format. JSON needs surrounding brackets ({}), and generally you need quotations around the variable name, and its value. The  I have used is just a placeholder for your username (don't want to reveal mine) - it is not an MM shortcut. The directory itself doesn't matter, it's just an example.

Comment: Hi @appirio Ciaran, can you explain how this resolved or should resolve the issue?

Comment: Is `<name>` a variable used by Sublime/MM?

Comment: @Bartley - The configuration files for MM are in JSON format. JSON needs surrounding brackets ({}), and generally you need quotations around the variable name, and its value.

Mike Chale - No, that's just a placeholder for your username. The directory itself doesn't matter, it's just an example.

Comment: @AppirioCiaran good one, best to edit your answer with your new information to make the answer itself more complete.

Comment: We can validate our workspace settings here http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0):

The actual explanation is much simpler, simply user "/" rather than "\"